# Why is my meteorjs not showing anything in the body?

Tags: html, meteor, spacebars

This is the HTML file I have. It's not showing the "hi", but it is showing the "Welcome to the ugly administrative side."

```
<head>
    Welcome to the ugly administrative side.

</head>

<body>
    hi
    {{#if currentUser}}
        Hello {{> loginButtons}}<br>
        {{> home}}
    {{else}}
        {{> loginButtons}}
    {{/if}}

</body>

<template name="home">
    {{#if adminFlag}}
        {{> adminPage}}
    {{else}}
        You aren't an administrative user, there's nothing for you here.
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

Comment: Try to output the simplest thing and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it was a glitch with TextMate, seeing as it kept unexpectedly closing. It started showing up properly when TextMate stopped acting up.

Comment: Do you have the accounts-ui package installed?